# Error loading collections You have gone over your daily usage limits

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My app is still in development and I uploaded about 35.6 MB of images to firebase storage.
suddenly the application stopped working and I cannot access the Firestore From the Firebase console. it shows the message

```
Error loading collections   
You have gone over your daily usage limits
```

Is it possible that I have reached the limit and we are only 3 people currently using the application? Or is there an error in the firebase?

- Will the problem be solved if I enabled payment in my account?
- How much will I expect to pay monthly?

[image]

Comment: "Should I use Realtime Database instead of firestore?" That's a technology recommendation question, which is off-topic on Stack Overflow I recommend removing it, to prevent your question from being closed.

Comment: The screenshot and error message you show are for Cloud Firestore, but in your intro and tags you talk about Cloud Storage. Since you only show problems with Firestore, I removed the Storage tag.

Comment: Okay, I  thought they depended on each other. (reading documents and reading images)

Comment: Not in the Firebase products. In your application they may well be, but we can know that based on the information you shared so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite common to go over your free quota much earlier than you'd expect during development. During this phase developers usually keep the Firestore console open, and any data that the console reads is also charged. So you'll first want to check that, and see if you really need to keep the console open - or if you can see what you need in your app already, or with some dedicated queries.

> Will the problem be solved if I enabled payment in my account?

If you've hit the free quota of your project, moving the project onto the paid/Blaze plan will remove/increase that quota.

> How much will I expect to pay monthly?

Firestore pricing depends solely on your usage, so I recommend checking out the [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) page (and the calculator at the bottom)